# Product of an array using division[C#]

Tags: c#

I am just curious to know how to find a product of an array using division.

This is my code:

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 , 4};

int length = arr.Length;

int product =1;

foreach (var item in arr) {
   
   product *= item;

}

Console.WriteLine(product);
```

I am able to get *Product* which is 24. I know if I divide the *product* by each element of an array which gives me new array. Eg the solution would be [24, 12, 8, 6]; How would I achieve this.

**My approach is:** Construct an new empty array, then loop through it and then divide *product* by each *item* in an array, which looks something like this:

```
Division = product/item;
```

I'm not sure about this, can someone help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might try adding to a new `List<int>` inside a second `foreach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
int newArr = new int[length];

for(int i = 0;i < length;i++)
{
    newArr[i] = product / arr[i];
}
```

you can't use `foreach` because you are changing the array in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the code above

```
List<int> newArray = new List<int>();
foreach(var item in arr)
{
    newArray.Add(product/item);
}
```

You can change newArray to an array using `ToArray` after the loop.